# What is the default timeout setting in Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have azure api management instance which contains one operation which has backend call to azure function. I am facing issue that client who is calling my apim endpoint receiving 500 error due to  timeout at forward-request (after 30 sec), but at the backend processing continues and records are created in backend.
[image]
So in this situation client think record is not created but actually its created.

**1. What is the default timeout for APIM as documentation shows 300 seconds whereas it also states 240 as max timeout? So this is misleading**
[image]
**2. Backend processing doesn't stop so is this expected that apim is returning timeout error?**

Comment: Your client (the backend service) disconnects after 30 seconds. This has nothing to do APIM.  This can be configured in the backend. Maybe the backend is an Azure Function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout

Comment: but after timeout exception, azure function processing does not stop. So its not function which is throwing timeout but APIM. See the logs how it logs events after timeout as well. @MarkusMeyer

Comment: ok, I hope you are right

Comment: @Imgane5h  From the description i have understand that you are facing timed out issue while calling the backend through APIM. Have you tried calling your backend directly from your client by bypassing the APIM is this scenario is working fine could you please confirm on the same?

Comment: No I didn't try. I cant expose my backend directly to client. But based on above information its clear that backend works fine but APIM timed out after 30 sec. My Question is is 30 sec default one from APIM?

Comment: @Imgane5h No, the forward request policy has a default timeout set to 5 mins which means that if the connection keeps an idle with the backend for more than 5 mins, APIM will drop the connection.
You can override this value as documented here but need to keep in mind that values greater than 240 seconds may not be honored as the underlying network infrastructure can drop idle connections after this time.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ForwardRequest

Comment: @Imgane5h what does *your* code and *your* backend do? Increasing the timeout to cover up a runaway query is no solution. 30 seconds sounds suspiciously like a query execution timeout.

Comment: It calls dynamics api which create some records in dynamics